# PyQt threaded ftp: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QUrlInfo'

Tags: pyqt, signals, qthread

I have the need to download all files in an ftp directory.  I don't know the files in the dir at the time my program starts, so I want the program to list the contents of the dir, then download each of the files it finds.

I've made a little demo script that downloads a file from ftp & updates a progress bar while doing so.  The downloading & updating the progress bar works fine, however, I'm trying to do the next step which is to list the contents of some dir & download the files, and that part isn't working.

At the moment, I'm just trying to do a list on any directory & print the results to the command line.

When I try to do a listInfo.connect, I get an error message:

QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QUrlInfo'
(Make sure 'QUrlInfo' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

... as I understand it, qRegisterMetaType is not something that can be done in PyQt & is also a sign of a fundamental problem, and herein lies my problem.  I can do a commandFinished.connect and dataTransferProgress.connect without issue, but listInfo.connect doesn't seem to work (as I would expect it).

Any ideas how to correct this?

Here's some example code (pardon the length).  I would like to be able to print the listed files/urls from the function "lister".  Ultimately, I'd like to then have that function formulate new urls & pass them back to connectAndDownload to download each of the files (of course, this will require modifications to connectAndDownload, but we're not there yet).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork

class FtpWorker(QtCore.QThread):
    dataTransferProgress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int,int)
    def __init__(self,url,parent=None):
        super(FtpWorker,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ftp = None
        self.outFile = None
        self.get_index = -1

        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        self.connectAndDownload()
        self.exec_()

    def ftpCommandFinished(self, command_index, error):
        print "-----commandfinished-----",command_index

        if self.ftp.currentCommand == QtNetwork.QFtp.ConnectToHost:
            if error:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "FTP",
                        "Unable to connect to the FTP server at %s. Please "
                        "check that the host name is correct.")
            return

        if self.ftp.currentCommand == QtNetwork.QFtp.Get or command_index == self.get_index:
            if error:
                print "closing outfile prematurely"
                self.outFile.close()
                self.outFile.remove()
            else:
                print "closed outfile normally"
                self.outFile.close()

            self.outFile = None

    def ftpDataTransferProgress(self,a,b):
        self.dataTransferProgress.emit(a,b)


    def lister(self,url_info):
        print url_info.name()


    def connectAndDownload(self):
        if self.ftp:
            self.ftp.abort()
            self.ftp.deleteLater()
            self.ftp = None
            return

        self.ftp = QtNetwork.QFtp()
        self.ftp.commandFinished.connect(self.ftpCommandFinished)
        self.ftp.listInfo.connect(self.lister)
        self.ftp.dataTransferProgress.connect(self.ftpDataTransferProgress)

        url = QtCore.QUrl(self.url)

        print "connect",self.ftp.connectToHost(url.host(), url.port(21))
        print "login",self.ftp.login(url.userName(), url.password())


        print "Connecting to FTP server %s..." % str(url.host())

        import os
        fileName = os.path.basename(self.url)

        if QtCore.QFile.exists(fileName):
            print "removing '%s'" % fileName
            os.unlink(fileName)

        self.outFile = QtCore.QFile(fileName)
        if not self.outFile.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly):
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "FTP",
                    "Unable to save the file %s: %s." % (fileName, self.outFile.errorString()))
            self.outFile = None
            return

        tmp = self.ftp.list()
        print "starting list",tmp

        print "ftp.get(%s,%s)" % (str(url.path()), self.outFile)
        self.get_index = self.ftp.get(url.path(), self.outFile)



class AddProgresWin(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AddProgresWin, self).__init__(parent)

        self.thread = FtpWorker(url="ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/developerguides/qteffects/screenshot.png")

        self.thread.dataTransferProgress.connect(self.updateDataTransferProgress)

        self.nameLabel = QtGui.QLabel("0.0%")
        self.nameLine = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        self.progressbar = QtGui.QProgressBar()

        mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.progressbar, 0, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.nameLabel, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Processing")

        self.thread.start()

    def updateDataTransferProgress(self, readBytes, totalBytes):
        self.progressbar.setMaximum(totalBytes)
        self.progressbar.setValue(readBytes)
        perct = "%2.1f%%" % (float(readBytes)/float(totalBytes)*100.0)
        self.nameLabel.setText(perct)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.path)

    pbarwin = AddProgresWin()
    pbarwin.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a Qt bug.  From Phil Thompson, "It's arguably a Qt bug -it should call qRegisterMetaType() itself for any types used in signal arguments."

It was also brought to my attention that for this purpose, there's no need to thread, as QFtp is asynchronous & comes with its own signals.  I've reimplemented the ftp.list() (and associated signal handling) in the main thread & all is well.